# xkeyval's \presetkeys

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

Please is there a way to avoid *xkeyval* package bombing out in endless loop, as implied by the following simplified case?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{fam}{key1}[key1-def]{\def\x##1{#1*##1}}
\define@cmdkey{fam}[store@]{key2}[key2-def]{\setkeys{fam}{key1=#1}}
%\define@key{fam}{key3}[key3-def]{\def\keyvalue{#1}}
\presetkeys{fam}{key2=val2}{}
\setkeys{fam}{key1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

I get "If you really absolutely need more capacity, you can ask a wizard to enlarge me."

Answer (score 1):

I and Hendri Adriaens (the author of *xkeyval* package) agree that the following patch does solve the problem. We also agreed to collaborate to integrate *xkeyval*, *ltxkeys* and *skeyval* packages into *xkeyval2*, if we are able to find spare time.

```
\def\XKV@badsetkeys{%
  \@latex@error{You can't nest \noexpand\setkeys in preset keys.
    \MessageBreak That could cause an endless loop}\@ehd
}
\let\XKV@savsetkeys\setkeys
\def\XKV@usepresetkeys#1#2{%
  \XKV@presettrue
  \let\setkeys\XKV@badsetkeys
  \XKV@for@eo\XKV@fams\XKV@tfam{%
    \XKV@makehd\XKV@tfam
    \XKV@ifundefined{XKV@\XKV@header#2}{}{%
      \XKV@toks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\csname XKV@\XKV@header#2\endcsname}%
      \@expandtwoargs\XKV@s@tkeys{\the\XKV@toks}%
        {\XKV@naa\ifx\XKV@naa\@empty\else,\fi#1}%
    }%
  }%
  \let\setkeys\XKV@savsetkeys
  \XKV@presetfalse
}
```